# Master-detail hierarchy between a ListBox and a DataGrid

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, listbox

I would like to set a DataGrid.ItemsSource property according a ListBox.SelectedItem value so that whenever a category is selected in the ListBox, the DataGrid should display the appropriate collection.

Example :

ListBox has the following items :

- Artists
- Medias

(taken from this enumeration)

```
public enum Category
{
    Artists,
    Medias
}
```

Then the DataGrid should pick the associated collection from here :

```
public class MyCategories
{
    public IEnumerable<Media> Medias { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
}
```

However, ConverterParameter of DataGrid.ItemsSource does not allow a binding to be defined for it.

*A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'ConverterParameter' property of type 'Binding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.*

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay,
              Converter={StaticResource categoriesConverter},
              ConverterParameter={Binding ElementName=listBox1, Path=SelectedItem}}" />
```

How would one achieve this ?

Comment: Media and Artist are both Classes?   In the enum they are just strings.  Even a Dictionary&lt;string,IEnumerable&gt; is not going to work as the IEnumerable wants a type.

Comment: Yes they are classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create a class with both and name and an IEnumerable
In your case the IEnumerable is a class (not a string) and in the path you will need to include the name of the  property to display

```
<Window x:Class="Waster13.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EnumsPlus}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" x:Name="lbMaster"/>
        <ListBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=lbMaster, Path=SelectedItem.IEnum}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections;

namespace Waster13
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private List<EnumPlus> enumsPlus = new List<EnumPlus>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.DataContext = this;
            enumsPlus.Add(new Media("media1", new List<string>() { "m1", "m2" }));
            enumsPlus.Add(new Media("media2", new List<string>() { "m3", "m4" }));
            enumsPlus.Add(new Artist("artist1", new List<string>() { "a1", "a2" }));
            enumsPlus.Add(new Artist("artist2", new List<string>() { "a3", "a4" }));
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public List<EnumPlus> EnumsPlus { get { return enumsPlus; } }
    }
    public interface EnumPlus : IEnumerable
    {
        String Name { get; }
    }
    public class Media : EnumPlus
    {
        private string name;
        private IEnumerable iEnum;
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return (IEnumerator)iEnum.GetEnumerator();
        }
        public String Name { get { return name; } }
        public IEnumerable IEnum { get { return iEnum; } }

        public Media(string Name, IEnumerable IEnum)
        { name = Name; iEnum = IEnum; }
    }
    public class Artist : EnumPlus
    {
        private string name;
        private IEnumerable iEnum;
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return (IEnumerator)iEnum.GetEnumerator();
        }
        public String Name { get { return name; } }
        public IEnumerable IEnum { get { return iEnum; } }

        public Artist(string Name, IEnumerable IEnum)
        { name = Name; iEnum = IEnum; }
    }
}
```

Comment: How come you've been able to select Path=SelectedItem.IEnum ? Nothing pops out after SelectedItem so I had to create a ValueConverter for fetching the collection. Note I haven't copy/pasted your code but recreated something like it, second ListBox being a DataGrid and the IEnumerable being an IQueryable.

Comment: Because the SelectedItem has a property IEnum.

Comment: That's weird, I copy/pasted your code but it still not offers it. I know they are supposed to be fetched but they're not. I first thought because it was on another assembly and there was no public parameter-less constructor but that didn't fix it. What version of WPF do you use ? I'm currently using WPF 4.5

Comment: I am on 4.0.  But I cannot imagine it broke on 4.5. You did include using System.Collections;?

Comment: Yes I did, that is really strange I kept trying but without success, SelectedItem remains an Object. I'll create a new project and try again.